# LinkedIn Javascript API: Trouble passing id multiple IDs to IN.API.Profile

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

The following works perfectly:

```
IN.API.Profile("me", "ID1", "ID2")
.fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "interests"])
.result(function(result) {

  //Do something

});
```

but I get nothing back if I replace the IDs with a text var so:

```
var textVar = ("me", "ID1", "ID2");

 IN.API.Profile(textVar)
   .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "interests"])
   .result(function(result) {

     //Do something

  });
```

Suggestions appreciated

Comment: By the way, does Linkedln api supports write like facebook api? i.e does your application able to submit some data to the users of Linkedln?

Comment: Hi Said.  I haven't needed to write to LinkedIn, so not sure. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Finally realized "var testText" needed to be an array, not text.

Thanks everyone.